# CSS border / box shadow challenge

Tags: jquery, css

I'm creating three columns with divs, and I'm fiddling a little with borders and inset box shadow. I just can't seem to get it right. i need it to look like this:
 [image]

Here's what I have so far (disregard the radio buttons): [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WStTa/). The problem is the center column - the left inset box shadow and the border as well as the bottom timeslots don't look quite right.

```
.CalendarCon.num2 .timeSlot {box-shadow: 1px 0px 1px 0 #fff}
```

What am I missing? (The columns won't always have the same height, btw.)

If jQuery is needed it's ok.

Comment: what if you remove the inset box-shadow? http://jsfiddle.net/WStTa/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does [THIS EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WStTa/7/) work for you?

I've used `label`s instead of `div`s (to make each box clickable), got rid of the need for css3 selectors (you're welcome IE8), and have cut down the CSS:

```
.CalendarCon {float:left;width:112px;background-color:#eaeaeb;}
.CalendarCon .timeSlot, .CalendarCon h3 { font-size:12px; margin:0; border-top:1px solid #d6d6d6; border-right:1px solid #d6d6d6; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 #fff inset; text-align:center; display:block; padding:15px 10px; text-align:center;}
.CalendarCon {border-left:1px solid #d6d6d6; margin-left:-1px; border-bottom:1px solid #d6d6d6;}
.CalendarCon .timeSlot:hover {background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.02);}
.CalendarCon .timeSlot input {display:block; clear:both;  margin:auto; border:1px solid #eee;}
```

Comment: Actually, changing the divs into labels has made my life much easier. Why didn't I think of that before? Brilliant solution. Thanks a lot, man.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the following 2 styles to be

```
.CalendarCon {float:left;width:112px;background-color:#eaeaeb; border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;}
.CalendarCon .timeSlot:last-child {border-bottom:1px solid #d6d6d6;}
```

[You should achieve what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/WStTa/4/)

(ps not sure why you want the white line on the bottom as it doesn't match the rest of the shadow effect)

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify this :

```
.CalendarCon h3 {
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px 0 #fff, 1px 1px 1px 0 #fff inset;
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    height:40px;
    margin-bottom:0;
    border-bottom:0;
}
.CalendarCon .timeSlot {
    border:1px solid #d6d6d6;
    border-bottom:0;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px 0 #fff, 1px 1px 1px 0 #fff inset;
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px 10px;
}
.CalendarCon .timeSlot:last-child {
    border-bottom:1px solid #d6d6d6;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ARZAz/)**

Hope this help.